# Integrating Beyond Compare 3 with base clearcase version 8 on Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: windows, integration, clearcase, beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

Has anyone succeeded in this integration? Previously I integrated fine with Clear Case version 6 on Windows xp.

Now with Clearcase 8 (I am using dynamic views) I have edited the map file as per instructions (and as I did with old clearcase)  and restarted clearcase .. but any compare just pulls up the old clearcase diff tool, never BC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is finally working fine. I added beyond compare 3 - and without quotes - and also the full path. Here is an example of one of the lines

```
text_file_delta     compare             C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe
```

I notice that relative path also works, so maybe it was just having quotes around the path

```
text_file_delta     compare             ..\..\..\..\..\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe
```